# How to wire in a collaborator into a Jersey resource?

Tags: java, jersey

I have a method to start up my application:

```
public void start() throws IOException {
    final Map<String, String> initParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
    initParams.put("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "com.example");
    threadSelector = GrizzlyWebContainerFactory.create(baseUri, initParams);
}
```

And I have a [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) resource class:

```
@Path("/notification")
public class NotificationResource {
    // HOW DO I INJECT THIS GUY?
    private MySampleCollabolator  mySampleCollabolator;    

    @POST
    public void create() {
        System.out.println("Hello world"); 
    }
}
```

What is the proper way of handling dependencies? I would like my resources to 
communicate with other objects, how do I wire them together?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can implement [InjectableProvider](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/1.19.1/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/inject/InjectableProvider.html). For example:

```
@Provider
public class FooProvider
    implements InjectableProvider<Resource, Type> {

    public ComponentScope getScope() {
        return ComponentScope.PerRequest;
    }

    public Injectable getInjectable(ComponentContext ic, Resource resource, Type type) {
        return new Injectable() {
            public Object getValue() {
                return new Foo();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

and then annotate field in your resource:

> @Resource private Foo foo;

Answer (score 1):

If you're comfortable using spring, then the best way is to use the [jersey spring api](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/contribs/jersey-spring/index.html) module (installed as an additional dependency). It's released in lockstep with Jersey.

The [javadoc page](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.8/contribs/jersey-spring/com/sun/jersey/spi/spring/container/servlet/package-summary.html) has a decent example to get you started.

Comment: Thanks Sean. Do you have any ideas how to make it work if I am not using XML at all? I start up my app like this:        GrizzlyWebContainerFactory.create(baseUri, initParams); Or may be there is a way I could skip using spring? It is a bit over the top for me right now to introduce spring.